# Can't get my Belkin N150 wireless adapter to work, stuck on "setting network address"

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, kubuntu

I have installed Kubuntu 15.10 and everything is great, aside from the fact that I just cannot get my Belkin N150 Wireless USB adapter to connect to my wifi.

It shows my Network, but when I try to connect it gets stuck on "Setting network address", until it shows the notification "IP configuration is unavailable".

What makes this so strange is that I can get the adapter to work without any issues on other Linux distros like Mint or Manjaro, it's just Kubuntu that wont work with it.

I can also use different wireless adapters, I borrowed my brother's and it connected just fine.

I'm super confused by this all and really need some help!

Thanks a million,

Alex

Answer (score -1):

- Open or search for the application `Software Sources`.
- Click the rightmost tab: "proprietary drivers" or so.
- Check all the boxes listed. (pass if none are)
- When a window appears asking to update, click `Ok` or so.
- When that finishes, click the leftmost tab and ensure that both `universe` and `multiverse` are checked (or whatever).
- Close Software Sources, then open a terminal and run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- Reboot.
- Try to connect to WiFi.
- If this does not work, search online for how to install proprietary drivers for your device.

Comment: Why da downvote tho?